# Is there a difference between using accuracy_score with shuffled labels and without?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, data-science

So first I have sorted labels, for example, 40 rows labeled A, and then other 40 rows labeled B, 40 rows labeled C and then 40 labeled D. all in this order making a list of 160 labels.

after predicting with both labels(shuffled and unshuffled)
Here are my scores:

```
shuffled:
0.14375

not shuffled:
0.30434782608695654
```

my question is:
shouldn't both be the same? or this is normal and I'm not making a mistake?

Comment: Does this happen consistently? What are you using to make your predictor? Do you use all the data for training? (Are you shuffling *all* the data columns, or just the labels)?

Comment: How are you shuffle and split your train/test model?

Comment: @doctorlove no, this is the first time. i'm using a brute force predictor. yes, I'm using all the data. i'm shuffling everything together.

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "brute force predictor" - can you provide the code where you set up your predictor? See, some algos starts with clusters etc at the first few points, so a re-order might give different results. Others start with random numbers or points, so the same run on either shuffled or unshuffled data may give different results. Tell us what you are doing and we might be able to explain what's happening.

Comment: Do any of the inputs have the same features but different labels?

Comment: @doctorlove I just want to know if this is supposed to happen or not. so my question is if I reordered everything, should the accuracy be different? or it will always be the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many circumstances under which the results can change when the order of the training inputs' order is changed.

For example, The [Nearest neighbours](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/neighbors.html#brute-force) warns

> Regarding the Nearest Neighbors algorithms, if two neighbors k+1  and
>   k  have identical distances but different labels, the result will
>   depend on the ordering of the training data.

Other algorithms will use the first few points to get started, and that  can change your results.

Others will give different results when rerun, even if you don't change the order of inputs. Many machine learning algorithms use random numbers - this can make the results vary slightly. It's worth doing a few runs and giving an average when that happens.